# Read the ActiveCell content in Excel using VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I'm trying to read the ActiveCell from within an Excel Add-in but not getting very far. Anyone any ideas?

```
Excel.Window W = this.Application.ActiveWindow as Excel.Window;
Excel.Range R = W.ActiveCell as Excel.Range;
MessageBox.Show(R.Value2.ToString());
```

The Exception being thrown on the last line is: -

> Cannot obtain fields or call methods
>   on the instance of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'
>   because it is a proxy to a remote
>   object.

I tried .Value, and it says: -

> Property, indexer, or event 'Value' is
>   not supported by the language; try
>   directly calling accessor methods
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.get_Value(object)'
>   or
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Value(object,
>   object)'

On trying get_Value() I get the initial Exception again.

> Cannot obtain fields or call methods
>   on the instance of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'
>   because it is a proxy to a remote
>   object.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Phil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R.Text.ToString(); will get you the text from the cell

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Activewindow. modified your code as follows
Excel.Range R = this.Application.ActiveCell as Excel.Range; 
if (R != null)
  MessageBox.Show(R.Value2);

Note: ActiveCell can be null if user have not chosen a cell in the active sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Is this of any use: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/f21c7cf4-fbfd-4496-a593-781eb751d580

It suggests turning off proxies for debugging purposes, hinting that the error message you are seeing may be masking a lower level COM error.