# Excel Add-In C# get value of active cells

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013, add-in

I used the Visual Studio 2013 Add-In Template and made a custom task pane with a simple button it.  Now I am trying to read the value of the active cells when the button is pressed.  This is what I have so far:

```
    namespace CostCenterAddIn
    {
         public partial class CostCenterControl : UserControl
         {
             public CostCenterControl()
             {
                 InitializeComponent();
             }

             private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {

                Excel.Window W = this.Application.ActiveWindow as Excel.Window;
                Excel.Range R = W.ActiveCell as Excel.Range;
                MessageBox.Show(R.Text.ToString());
             }
         }
    }
```

I copied this example: [Read the ActiveCell content in Excel using VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767338/read-the-activecell-content-in-excel-using-vsto)

However, I am getting the following error:

'CostCenterAddIn.CostCenterControl' does not contain a definition for 'Application' and no extension method 'Application' accepting a first argument of type 'CostCenterAddIn.CostCenterControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

For some reason I can't access Application.

This is my code for "ThisAddIn.cs":

```
    namespace CostCenterAddIn
    {
       public partial class ThisAddIn
       {
           private CostCenterControl myUserControl1;
           private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane;

           private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
           {
              this.Application.WorkbookBeforeSave += new                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeSaveEventHandler(Application_WorkbookBeforeSave);

              myUserControl1 = new CostCenterControl();
              myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "Cost Center Converter");
              myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
           }

           private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
           {
           }

           #region VSTO generated code

           /// <summary>
           /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
          /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
          /// </summary>
          private void InternalStartup()
          {
             this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
             this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
          }

          #endregion
        }
     }
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: In your project directory, do you see a file called ThisAddIn.Designer.cs?  If so, can you open that and verify the namespace name that's in that file matches what you have specified above?  Also, if they do match, check and see if Application is defined in that file.  You could also check and make sure ThisAddIn.Designer.cs is properly included in your csproj file, though I'd expect that to cause many other errors if it were missing...

Comment: Type `Globals.` and check the intelli-sense. You should something like `Globals.ThisAddin.ThisWorkbook....`

Comment: Thanks me how, that fixed the issue! I used Globals.ThisAddin.Application