# Converting .Selection.Find.Style from Word VBA to C#

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word

I am converting an old legacy VB program to C#. One of the methods involves find (and return) text in a Word document that match a specific Word Style.

in the original VB code, there is the following line of code:

```
With objword
   ...
   .Selection.Find.Style = .ActiveDocument.Styles(StyleCode)
   ...
End With
```

This is what I am trying to do in C# (using Word Interop):

```
_wordObject.Selection.Find.Style = _wordObject.ActiveDocument.Styles[styleCode];
```

When I try to compile the program I get an error message that says:

```
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find.Style' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find.get_Style()' or 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find.set_Style(ref object)'
```

When I try to use get_Style, I am told that it does not take any parameters, and to use the index property, OR that I cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'method group'

What do I need to do in C# to find text in a Word Document by Word Style?

Comment: Is Styles a method or an array? Does calling it with non-square brackets work? Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2300917/495455 - try using an alternative to ActiveDocument

Comment: .Selection.Find.Style appears to be a property, but it looks like I cannot assign a value to it. Also, I did not understand the link that was sent. Again, I just want to find text in a Word Document by using Word Styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try and do what the Error Message says and call accessor method:

```
Style normalStyle = document.Styles[-1]; //Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal
_wordObject.Selection.Find.set_Style(ref normalStyle);
```

I dont have access to Visual Studio to test this atm.

Comment: Where are you getting "document" from in the first line?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeremy Thompson for providing the correct answer. This is the code I have been able to use, to find text via Word Style:

```
_wordObject.Selection.Find.set_Style(_wordObject.ActiveDocument.Styles[styleCode].NameLocal);
```

I should note that ReSharper tells me to "Use indexed property", but when I try to do that, I get an error: "Indexer has 0 parameters but is invoked with 1 argument".